# Changing default openVPN IP in linux server

Tags: ip, openvpn

The problem is that we have a public OpenVPN service. Pay €9.95 and you 
get an OpenVPN account at currently half a dozen of servers for a 
month. This means there are always and will always be some people who 
create a certain amount of abuse or trouble. On the long run, the 
external IP every OpenVPN user gets assigned is prohibited from editing 
Wikipedia, it might be banned by e-gold and on some popular webforums, 
one-click-hosters, etc.  Not a pleasant experience for the 97% of our 
customers who use our service responsibly and legitimately to regain 
their privacy.

So even if I could change the assigned external IP every few months; e. 
g. from 216.xx.xx.164 to 216.xx.xx.170, it would help us a lot to combat 
this abuse and to provide our paying clients with "fresh" IP addresses 
that aren't banned or restricted on some popular Internet sites and 
services, yet.

Does anybody know how to change the first IP address assigned to the 
public interface in CentOS?  So that e.g. OpenVPN in future doesn't give 
our OpenVPN clients the external IP 123.xx.xx.164 but rather 
123.xx.xx.170?

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know how your routing looks like but i guess at the exit point you can set simple SNATing rules on ipfilter telling which source ip address should be used for outgoing [ from the vpn tunnels ] connections.

something simple as:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 123.x.x.170

can do the trick. i assume 10.0.0.0/24 is a range of source ips assigned to vpn clients.